# Why does contenteditable="true" generate dirty html

Tags: html

When I enable contenteditable like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     Hello world
</div>
```

The content added to it by just typing and using Enter generates bad/ dirty HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     Hello world
     <div><br></div>
     <div>How are you doing. I am doing just fine!</div>
     <div><br></div>
     <div><br></div>
     <div>New line of text</div>
</div>
```

As you can see for every page break there is a `<div>` used with a `<br>` inside. Why is this, and is this correct semantic HTML. In my mind it would more be like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     <p>Hello world</p>
     <p>How are you doing. I am doing just fine!</p>
     <br>
     <p>New line of text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `textarea` instead?

Comment: It seems each browser vendor has its own approach, there is not yet a defined standard practice.

Comment: @BramVanroy Because I want to edit HTML not plain text. BTW, I am just experimenting with contenteditable and I want to know why it behaves like this. Answers like: 'Just use teaxtarea' or 'Use tinymce' is not where I am waiting for!

Comment: There's a reason why I posted this as a comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It all comes down to history. The `contenteditable`attribute was originally Microsoft specific. It was added to IE5.5 way before HTML5 existed. As it proved to be useful but there was no spec, each vendor reverse engineered it [1] and added it with their own little twist (as tends to happen when there’s no spec.) As each vendor implemented it differently and popular web sites [2] that used it worked around those differences, it was difficult for each of the vendors to standardise on a common behaviour without breaking those sites. So we ended up being stuck with what we have.

Opera for instance added it in much the way you said you prefer with <p> elements when you hit enter, while Safari/WebKit used <div>s and Firefox uses <br/>s.

1. Some [reverse engineering notes](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/07/more-contenteditable) from Opera’s Anne van Kesteren
2. I remember Writely (now renamed Google Docs) as a prime example when I worked at Opera.

Answer (score 0):

The `contenteditable="true"` attribute has been defined just as making the element content editable by the user. The user interface has been left browser-dependent. This also applies to handling Enter, which actually varies a lot. Some browsers generate `br` elements, some generate `div` elements, and some generate `p` elements, etc.

The question about “semantic markup” is meaningless here. The browser has no way of knowing what the user means by the input, so it cannot possibly select markup that corresponds to the meaning – even in the loose sense where the slogan “semantic markup” is usually used, namely *structure*. For example, if the user types some text, bolds it, and presses Enter, he may well mean it to be a heading – but the browser really can’t know (and still less can it guess whether it should be, say, `h2` or `h3`).

There are two ways to deal with the Enter issue. You could have an `onkeypress` event handler for the element and try to handle Enter your way. This would not affect copy and paste operations, though; when multi-line text is inserted, browsers deal with line breaks differently.

The other way is to handle the diversity in the processing of the user-entered content. There you could canonicalize things the way you want. The user might get a wrong impression, from the way his content is shown in a browser, though.